# How to update parameters in pytorch with multiple loss functions?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have met some problems in updating parameters while training model. For instance, I have 2 loss-functions: `loss1` and `loss2`, let `loss` = `loss1 + loss2`. The model has **feature extractor layers** and **classifier layers**. And I want to update the parameters in **feature extractor layers** using `loss` and the parameters in **classifier layers** using `loss1`. How can I do that in pytorch???
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Let `fe` be the feature extractor layer and `fc` the classifier layer. One approach is to perform two backward passes:

- the first one on `loss2` with the `fc` layer gradients deactivated,
- the second one on `loss1` on both layers `fc` and `fe`.

As a result, `fc` should have the gradients relevant to `loss1`, while `fe` will have gradients from both `loss1` and `loss2`, *i.e.* `loss`.

```
>>> fc.requires_grad_(False)
>>> loss2.backward(retain_graph=True)
>>> fc.requires_grad_(True)
>>> loss1.backward()
```

**Do make sure this is the desired result you are looking for.**